# Server error when accessing 'replies' section

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, comment-replies

Go to chat user profile. Click "replies"

Page doesn't load for quite a bit of time.

Eventually I get this:

[image]

Honestly, I like the funny cat picture better than I would have liked my replies but I thought I'd let you know about the bug :)

Here is the HTTP response if that's helpful

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /error?aspxerrorpath=/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum
Set-Cookie: .ASPXBrowserOverride=; expires=Thu, 13-Jun-2013 02:28:42 GMT; path=/
Date: Fri, 14 Jun 2013 02:29:12 GMT
Content-Length: 171
```

**Update** : I've verified this happens in another browser (Internet Explorer).

Moreover. When I get pinged and click on the green (1) sign. It works. Only when I manually go and click on the replies button it fails.

I also conclude that clicking on any option inside replies other than `auto` or when clicking on replies directly, works. Choosing another option works consistently.

Comment: looks cat cant bear that much pressure they need unicorn

Comment: Is this still happening? The errors in the log make me think this was a temporary issue, and it works fine for me right now.

Comment: @balpha All better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error logs it looks like a brief network hickup on our side. Given that this was a very short timeframe and hasn't appeared again, I'm happy to shrug this of as a temporary issue.

Comment: It has appeared again! I'm currently experiencing this problem. Can you confirm or deny this is a network hiccup?

Comment: I can't deny it and it's not unlikely. We're in the middle of some [infrastructure happenings](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/126135656099/data-center-failover-august-8-2015), it wouldn't be unusual. The only strange thing is: I certainly see your errors in the exception log -- but you're alone, nothing else around the same time. The error is a SQL connection timeout, which can be caused by network issues, but in that case you'd expect more than just one affected user. It's back to working, so for now I'll assume coincidence, but I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: It's not back to working for me, I still have the same error. Looks like it might be a persistent issue?

Comment: Hmm you're right, it's back to broken. Looking.

Comment: Fixed now. Horrible performance of a query, but it depended on how long ago you last spoke, which is why I didn't see it earlier (after you'd been away for a while).